# How do you update the Apple TV Developer Kit? tvOS software not available via iTunes

Tags: apple-tv, tvos

I was the lucky winner of an Apple TV Developer Kit, and received it today.

When I plug the device into my TV, I am directed to first plug it in to a Mac with iTunes.

However, when I try to `Restore Apple TV...` the latest version of iTunes says:

> Software for this Apple TV is not currently available. Make sure you have the latest version of iTunes and try again.

[image: Can't restore via iTunes]

How do I install the correct software and use this device?

Comment: Did your Apple TV come with the necessary cable to connect it to your Mac? I have one coming in the second batch and don't want to have to wait another day ordering a USB-C cable!

Comment: @lukech yes, it comes with a USB-C cable. My first one! It's a cheap black one, though, not up to snuff with Apple's usual cable quality.

Comment: Better than nothin'!

Comment: Just in case anyone else stumbles across this, the second round of Dev kits did NOT come with USB-C cables. I had to wait a whole extra day, like a caveman :)

Comment: @lukech — Mine (second round) DID come with a USB-C cable. Oddly, it also came with a Lightning cable, which I have no idea yet why.

Comment: To charge the remote :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The Apple TV Developer Kit tvOS beta is not yet available via iTunes.

Download the tvOS beta here:
https://developer.apple.com/tvos/download/

Hold <kbd>Option</kbd> when clicking the `Restore Apple TV...` button in the screenshot above.

Then select the `.ipsw` you just downloaded to install the tvOS software to your Apple TV Dev Kit.